# Div content doesn't changes on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with changing div's content. I make an ajax call first and receive an JSON array from server. So far, so good. Then, I want to change several div's content to what I've received from server. The problem is that content doesn't changes on the first click. Response is OK every time, I've checked with Fiddler and in my code, that I am receiving correct response. But, mystery remains why are div's on my page not changed with the first click Why I have to click twice every time? I've spend hours figuring this out, tried everything, nothing seems logical. Here's my code (project is MVC 4):

```
$('#btnsearch').click(function ()
{
    var searchStr = $('#txtSearch').val();
    var noOfPages = 1;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        datatype: 'json',
        url: $('#btnsearch').data('request-url'),/*URL from Razor's page*/
        data: { pageNo: noOfPages, searchString: searchStr },/*MVC 4 call*/
        success: function (jsontext)
        { 
            $('#hiddenSearchResult').val(jsontext);
        },
        error: function ()
        {
            alert('Error when searching!');
        }
    });

    var json = $('#hiddenSearchResult').val();
    if (json.length === 0){ alert('result is empty!');
    return;}/*with empty json, parsing throws error*/
    json = JSON.parse(json);
    if (json.Content == undefined) return;

    for (var i = 0; i < json.Content.length; i++) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:

                $('#snippetsdivinner').html(json.Content[i].ContentString);
                break;
            case 1:

                $('#snippetsdivinner1').html(json.Content[i].ContentString);
                break;
            case 2:

                $('#snippetsdivinner2').html(json.Content[i].ContentString);
                break;
            case 3:

                $('#snippetsdivinner3').html(json.Content[i].ContentString);
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Isn't it due to the asynchronous call? The click doesn't wait that you receive data, and just continue to be executed.

Comment: I've put my code into success property of ajax and works like a charm. The only reason for not working was not waiting for async call to finnish, just like you've mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code from `var json = $('#hiddenSearchResult').val()` onwards is executed right after the AJAX request is started, but before it is completed, so at that time `$('#hiddenSearchResult')` isn't populated yet.

When you click the button for the second time, it has been populated by the completion of the AJAX request, and thus the code after your `$.ajax` executes as you expect.

You should move your code inside the `success` function to have it all executed when the AJAX request completes.

Answer (score 1):

It's asynchronous, you need to wait until you have the result

```
$('#btnsearch').click(function ()
{
   var searchStr = $('#txtSearch').val();
   var noOfPages = 1;

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    datatype: 'json',
    url: $('#btnsearch').data('request-url'),/*URL from Razor's page*/
    data: { pageNo: noOfPages, searchString: searchStr },/*MVC 4 call*/
    success: function (jsontext)
    { 
        if (jsontext.length === 0){ alert('result is empty!');
           return;
        }/*with empty json, parsing throws error*/
       var json = JSON.parse(jsontext);
       if (json.Content == undefined) return;

        for (var i = 0; i < json.Content.length; i++) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                $('#snippetsdivinner').html(json.Content[i].ContentString);
                break;
            case 1:
                $('#snippetsdivinner1').html(json.Content[i].ContentString);
                break;
            case 2:
                $('#snippetsdivinner2').html(json.Content[i].ContentString);
                break;
            case 3:
                $('#snippetsdivinner3').html(json.Content[i].ContentString);
                break;
        }
    }
        },
        error: function ()
        {
            alert('Error when searching!');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to also put all the code starting from

```
var json = $('#hiddenSearchResult').val();
```

inside the success callback of your ajax.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `datatype: 'json'` in your ajax call, you don't have to do `json = JSON.parse(json);`.

And what the other answers said about putting all your code in the `success` callback function.

Comment: If I don't use JSON.parse(json), then I can not traverse the JSON array and the code is not working.